# Introduction tour (with an alert box pointing elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I add a **introduction tour** (*with an alert box pointing elements*) to my website using html, css, bootstrap and javascript?

I am working on a project where I need to add an introduction tour with welcome message (appear just once) after the user signup.

Here I try to use [bootstrap tour](http://bootstraptour.com/), but it's not working

```js
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [{
      element: "#head",
      title: "Title of my step1",
      content: "Content of my step1"
    },
    {
      element: "#welcome",
      title: "Title of my step",
      content: "Content of my step"
    } {
      element: "#hew",
      title: "Title of my step",
      content: "Content of my step"
    },

  ]
});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="topbar">

    <header id="head">



      <ul>
        <li><a href="signup.html">job offer</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </header>


    <section id="reg_form_container">


      <br>
      <br>

      <div id="welcome">
        <pre><B><I>welcome to chitter,</I></B>
                   <I>    Thank You For Signing up with us.Chitter team want to welcome
                        you in our family.we feel proud to introduce you to a new
                         plateform where you can find multifunctioning site</I></PRE>
        <form id="tour"> <span><BUTTON  onclick="myFunction()">Take a SITE TOUR</BUTTON></span></form>
      </div>
      <div id="hew">
        <pre><B><I>welcome to my web site,</I></B>
                   <I>    Thank You For Signing up with us.Chitter team want to welcome
                        you in our family.we feel proud to introduce you to a new
                         plateform where you can find multifunctioning site</I></PRE>
        <form id="tour"> <span><BUTTON  onclick="myFunction()">Take a SITE TOUR</BUTTON></span></form>
      </div>


    </section>


    <footer></footer>


  </div>
```

Comment: This is an off topic question but this one looks nice: https://introjs.com/ - PS: "Not working" is a very poor description of a problem. Please visit [ask] and next time click `<>` and post a [mcve]

Comment: Start by fixing the errors in the snippet I made for you: Missing comma `} {
      element: "#hew",` and a comma too many at the end - also you cannot user v4 of bootstrap

Comment: You could use popovers in Boostrap, and then just use a bit jQuery to show the next "step" when clicking on a button. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/